# How do I know when Yakkety becomes available, from the repository?

Tags: release-management, stable-release-updates, 16.10

According to the [wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/YakketyYak/ReleaseSchedule), Yakkety is scheduled for it's final release on 2016-10-13.

However, the repository is [already there](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/). I guess that this is a beta release.

How do I know when it is final, purely from the repository? Is that even possible?

Comment: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases

Comment: Why was this downvoted? Non-technical, answerable questions about future releases are on topic.

Comment: No it is not... it is the 23rd.

Comment: @Rinzwind What do you mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a couple ways to determine whether a release is actually released or not, but you can't rely on the repositories for that basis.

1. **Check the [wiki page for Releases](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases)**.  When releases are actually released they get put on the "Current" list.
2. **Rely on the ubuntu-announce email list for release announcements.**  Ubuntu releases are announced there when they are officially released.

The above two are two of the best ways to find whether a release is actually released or not.  Consider that the fact `yakkety` exists means nothing - we can say the same in Debian for `testing` which is the 'next' Debian stable release which is still being updated etc. (though not as necessarily as rapidly as Ubuntu's in-development release).

---

**Relying solely on the Repositories is a bad idea**.

Comment: Okay, I guess it is not possible to know purely from the reposity. `yakkety-updates` and `yakkety-security` (and `yakkety` itself of course) already are there, while Yakkety hasn't been released yet. I guess I'll have to check the wiki then.